# Selecting a raffle winner with Excel when each player has multiple tickets

Tags: excel

I have to find a way to extract the winner in a raffle, using Excel.

Each player has a number of 'tickets', depending on their work achievements.

For instance: John has 300 tickets, Alice has 360 tickets, Ana has 410 tickets and so on.

I have to use Excel to randomly extract the winner with respect to each player's number of tickets. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide more extensive details and if you have some code too. It's a site to help you progress, so we need to see that you tried before coming here to ask.
Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is this info in Excel? why do you need to use Excel?

Comment: Think about your logic! You are picking 1 number out of 1170 possibilities - Ana has more tickets so she has more chance of winning in a random draw.  Not sure what you mean with "extract the winner with respect to each player's number of tickets"? Any modification to randomness based on number of tickets held has to be unfair to some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following layout:

[image]

Where in E2 I use:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,1070)
```

This will generate a uniformly distributed random number on the interval [1,1070], where the numbers are discrete.

You then define the intervals, in which the person wins with respect to the number of tickets.

I.e. Ana is represented by the interval [1,410], Alice by [411,770] and John by [771,1070].

You then look in which interval the random number lies, in order to select the winner with this in F2:

```
=IF(E2<=C$2,"Ana",IF(E2<=C$3,"Alice","John"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Marco! Your solution works for me.